# Box API 2.0 Create Folder 404 Error

Tags: box-api

I am using Box API version 2.0 on a mobile device.
I could able to get the file upload/download and get folder/file info working fine.

When I try to create a new folder, I get 404 as HTTP status.

Request URL address https://api.box.com/2.0/folders/0 (Creating folder in root).

Additional headers

1. Authentication header
2. L"Content-Type", L"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
3. L"Content-Length", 9

POST request body "name=test"

Any help would be appreciated.

Best regards,
Karthik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The post body [should be JSON](http://developers.box.com/docs/#api-basics), not a form. In your case you would send something like:

```
{
"name": "test"
}
```

Comment: I tried it is still not working.  I tried to send body as { 'name' : 'test' }  and   { "name" : "test" }  Below is the html response I get.  Not Found
The requested URL /api/ was not found on this server.

Comment: I am sending the body text as UTF-8, I hope that should be okay.

Comment: Finally got it working. It was combination of a stupid mistake I have made and wrong Json string. The json string should contain double quotes instead of single quote. Thanks for the help.